# Adobe AIR 512x512 Icons?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, icons, air

correct me if i'm wrong, but Adobe AIR currently only allows applications to have maximum size icon of 256x256.

- is there a way to supply an application with a 512x512 icon?
- will 512x512 icons be supported in the new upcoming Adobe AIR 2?

---

**update:**  AIR 2 still doesn't support importing 512x512 sized icons.

**update 2:**  AIR 2.7 still doesn't support importing icon sizes larger than 128 x 128.  ludicrous!

[image]

Comment: What do you want to use the large icon for?

Comment: for years, desktop applications have used 512 x 512 icons.  for example, when viewing an application in Finder on a Mac with Quick Look or in Cover Flow view, if the icon is only 256 x 256 it appears pixelated.

Comment: also, i was wrong.  AIR 2 Settings only supports importing icons up to 128x128.  that's just ridiculous.  i've added a screenshot to my original post

Comment: This should be feature request to Adobe.

Comment: good idea.  i've sent in a request.  i suggest others do the same.

Comment: http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=0DFA3E60-B0E1-44B4-9387-DC2D4E956F2B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while larger icons are not officially supported by Adobe, until then, i've discovered that it's pretty easy to include your own larger sized icons for AIR applications with native installers - at least on .dmg installers for Mac OS X.

with Mac OS X, you can drag the installer out of the .dmg onto your desktop, right-click the installer application to "show package contents", jump thru the folders until you see Icon.icns and then simply replace that with your own Icon.icns file.  after that, you can just repackage the installer into a new .dmg.  it's kind of a hassle, but it beats having pixelated icons.

this method requires you to build your native installer with an icon, however, foolishly, the included .png icon is never deleted from the bundle by the installer, even though it's only used once to create the Icon.icns file.  therefore, i suggest you only import a 16x16 .png white square with a tiny file size.  if you try deleting it the installer will say the package is corrupt, which it is since the application.xml file refers to the included icon.  removing the icon entry from the .xml will result in the installer not using your custom Icon.icns file.

for those who don't know how to make an .icns file on Mac.  you can download/install XCode developer tools and use the included program called "Icon Composer".  it's a basic drag-and-drop .icns file creator.

i'm not sure how this process can be emulated on Windows or Linux, so if anyone reading knows please post an answer.

Comment: But that sort of defeats the whole purpose of being cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-6fd06f0f1293d3b33ea-7ffc) 512x512 is supported in AIR 2.0

Comment: interesting.  i've manually written the tag in the descriptor file and included the file but i'm receiving incorrect argument when packaging.  can you get this to work with Flash Professional CS5?

Comment: sounds like bad command line syntax... can you paste the command you're using to package the app? When I package the app I use the Flex SDK and the ADT command line tool

Comment: i've attempted this with AIR 2.7 SDK using ADT on the command line to package my AIR application.  it doesn't throw any errors now, but writing `<icon><image512x512>myIcon.png</image512x512></icon>` in the descriptor file and including the icon file with the command line package is ignored.  the package is created with the default system icon.  it still doesn't work.

Comment: These links look pretty clear that it should work... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f3cb56e2a12cc36970aa-8000.html

Comment: according to that link it will work on iOS.  i'm referring to Deskop applications (Windows / Mac / Linux).  now this is even more ridiculous since it's available for iOS.  try it.  let me know if you can make it work.